# Is there a way in R to get table1 to calculate percentages by group based on total sum of a column, rather than by counting rows?

Tags: r

I'm working in R, looking for a way to make a nice table. For each first name or last name, I want the percentage of all individuals counted at each site who have that name, and the sum of individuals with that name next to the percentage. This seems to only calculate percentages based on the number of rows, rather than the actual count data. Not necessarily married to `table1` if there are other functions/packages that would do the trick!

Here is some example code:

```
set.seed(123)
    dat <- data.frame(
      site = factor(sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 100, replace = TRUE)),
      count = (sample(1:150, 100, replace = TRUE)),
      first.name = factor(sample(c("John", "Sue", "Bob", "Mary", "Cara"), 100, replace = TRUE)),
      last.name =  factor(sample(c("Williams", "Smith", "Lee"), 100, replace = TRUE)))
    
library(table1)
tab<- table1(~ last.name + first.name|site, #only counts rows, doesn't sum "Count" column
                                data = dat, 
                                render.continuous = ("Sum(Count) (PCTnoNA=100*Count/Sum(Count))"),
                                digits= 1) 

tab
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to trick `table1` into giving you what you want by making a data frame that has `sum(dat$count) == 6873` rows. That is not difficult:

```
idx <- rep(rownames(dat), dat$count)
length(idx)
# [1] 6873
dat.big <- dat[idx, ]
table1(~ last.name + first.name|site, data = dat.big)
```

[image: Table]

Comment: That was exactly what I needed, thank you so much!!

Comment: I've revised the example using `set.seed(123)`.

Answer (score 1):

Update: With the hint of dcarlson(many thanks!) here is a `gtsummary` solution:

```
library(gtsummary)
library(dplyr)
dat.big %>%
  tbl_summary(by = site) %>% 
  add_overall()
```

[image]

Are you looking for such a solution:

```
table1(~ last.name + first.name|site, data=dat)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking time to look. Similar, but not quite; I added a set.seed above to make this replicable, but in this case I'd be looking for a table just like that, but with the Overall N= 7637 (this is what I get when I run sum(dat$count). So the percentages I'm looking for would be out of the total sum of count for each column

Comment: Thanks! Nice to have another way to do it!